# Is there any way to get 100% of branch coverage?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, code-coverage

My task is to cover the whole solution with tests and reach 100% branch and sequence coverage.

I have this method with if statement:

```
public string ConvertToOrder(string cartCode)
{  
    var cart = CartService.GetCartByCode(cartCode);
    if (cart == null || cart.ItemCount == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("CartCode does not exist");
    }
}
```

I have been able to check only 3 scenarios out of 4.
1.when `cart` is not `null` and `itemCount == 0`
2.when `cart` is not `null` and `itemCount != 0`
3.when `cart` is `null` and `itemCount == 0`
4.Forth scenario is not reasonable as i am not able to add item to a `null` object in my test.

Is there any tool that supports that kind of cases and will show 100% coverage on that? or any kind of way to cover the 4th scenario?

Comment: I'm confused. If `cart` is `null`, how can there be any item count at all? #3 doesn't appear to have any meaning whatever - something can only be equal to 0 if it exists in the first place.

Comment: Now that I think about it, the third possible scenario is just cart is null.
Then why the coverage tool shows me that 3 out of 4 cases are covered?

Comment: Which tool are you using? That does seem incorrect to me, because by definition `itemCount == 0` and `itemCount != 0` have no meaning in the case that `cart` is `null`.

Comment: If you write code that checks for conditions that can't occur, it will be impossible to write tests for those conditions. Either way, you haven't specified what the 4th condition is. Doesn't the code coverage highlight what is and isn't covered?

Comment: as a side note, 100% code coverage is not really useful and should not be the aim of any project, I would say.Enforcing such a rule results in useless tests added just for the sake of the percentage coverage.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I use Typemock's coverage tool

Comment: @ScottHannen unfortunately it doesn't show the the case description, only the amount of times the line of code was executed

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu I agree, but for the beginning i want to reach 100% branch and sequence in the first part of the project

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a fourth scenario here. The following three scenarios will give complete coverage for your code:

1. `cart` is not `null` and `itemCount == 0`
2. `cart` is not `null` and `itemCount != 0`
3. `cart` is `null`

C# (like many programming languages) will evaluate the first operand `cart == null` and if that is true not evaluate the second operand. Simply this is because once the first operand is true we know the answer is true. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators) from Microsoft which covers this behavior of the `||` operator.

Your question implies that a tool is telling you that you don't have 100% coverage with the first three scenarios. If so, it would be worth looking into why that tool doesn't believe you have 100% coverage.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I work at Typemock - the unit testing company
The solution coverage tool doesn't know when to ignore these impossible to reach scenarios.
You will have to ignore these cases for now.
In order to make it easier to locate these hard cases, we advise using the HTML export in which you can see the number of times the if statement was executed and calculate the coverage manually, just to make sure you didn't miss any possible scenario